# Solace topic subscription with correlationId

Tags: c#, .net-core, messagebroker, solace

I subscribe to topics like that:

```
var topics = new string[]{
    "TOP/IC/*/A/>", 
    "TOP/IC/*/B/>",
    "ANY/*/STRU/CTURE"
    // etc... 
};
foreach(var t in topics)
{
    var topic = ContextFactory.Instance.CreateTopic(t);
    var sessionReturnCode = _session.Subscribe(topic, false); // _session is ISession
}
```

Incomming message has full topic name information. E.g. `TOP/IC/ANY/A/N123/XFDJK985`.

I would like to know from which subscription the message comes. Is it possible? (`correlationId`, whatever...). If yes, sample please.

Comment: Your topics seems to be incorrect - valid wildcards are `#` (multi-level) and `+` (single-level). Also notice that the broker will replace an existing subscription if a new subscription with the same topic filter for this session is received. Since there is no real difference for the client what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The wildcards are ok, see https://docs.solace.com/PubSub-Basics/Wildcard-Charaters-Topic-Subs.htm

Comment: I see, this is `SMF` and no `MQTT` - you should get rid of the tag

Comment: Sorry, yes, it is SMF. Tags updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Solace .NET API, by default, Direct messages are dispatched to the same receive callback or delegate that is configured for the Session. However, it is possible to use special receive callbacks or delegates to handle Direct messages that are published to specific Topics. This functionality is also known as topic dispatching because messages with a specific Topic are dispatched to a specific callback or delegate.

More information is available here: https://docs.solace.com/Solace-PubSub-Messaging-APIs/API-Developer-Guide/Receiving-Direct-Message.htm